# Enable buffer flow progress in the JW Player control bar

Tags: flash, jwplayer, mediaplayerservices

I have a rtmp on demand stream (delivered by Wowza server) and I have configured it using JWPlayer. Its quite working well and I want to add the blow flow progress in the JWplayer control bar just like YouTube video player buffer flow progress.

Here is my JW player code:

```
<body>
    <div id='mediaspace'>JW test Player with buffer enabled</div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
            'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
            'file': 'mp4:path1/revolution.2012.101.hdtv-lol.mp4',
            'provider': 'rtmp',
            'frontcolor': '000000',
            'lightcolor': '000000',
            'screencolor': '000000',
            'bufferlength': '20',
            'streamer': 'rtmp://198.105.211.36:1935/mediacache',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'width': '700',
            'height': '400'
          });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

RTMP only stores enough buffer for the video to play without pausing, that's the reason don't see any buffer in JWPlayer.

**Long Answer**

YouTube uses [HTTP Pseudo-Streaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28855/pseudo-streaming-in-flash) to deliver it's content which allows complete buffering of the video. You are currently using [RTMP](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming) to stream the video which doesn't have a real buffer.

From the [JWPlayer support forum](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/bug-reports/25760/rtmp-no-buffering/):

> When the player is playing content from an RTMP server, the buffer is not exposed. This is because unlike progressive download or HTTP pseudo-streaming, RTMP will only download enough of the content to display it without having to pause, so the player doesn't report buffer percentages.

If you would like your viewers to be able to seek to not-yet-downloaded parts of a video and be able to buffer the videos (good for slow internet connections) at the same time you could switch to [HTTP Pseudo-Streaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28855/pseudo-streaming-in-flash).

Answer (score 0):

Generally Wowza RTMP delivers the stream as chunks. If I pause the stream in player, the wowza server also pause the chunks to player. This causes we will not get data/chunks from the server. So clear I hope buffering is not possible.

For HTTP Pseudo streaming, its not like that, its using progressive download methods. so buffering is possible.

Refer for more : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video